How can we find general solution of $8x^2-7=y^2$ in integers.
$8x^2-7=y^2$
I tried this:
$8(x^2-1)=y^2-1$
$8(x^2-1)=(y-1)(y+1)$
Let $x^2-1 = a*b$
I made cases:
$y-1 = 8a , y+1 = 1b$
$y-1 = 4a , y+1 = 2b$
$y-1 = 2a , y+1 = 4b$
$y-1 = 1a , y+1 = 8b$
but wasn't able to continue further.

$y^2-2X^2=-7$ is a generalized Pell equation

solutions to that include $(X_n,y_n)$, where $(1+2\sqrt2)(3+2\sqrt2)^n=y_n+X_n\sqrt2$

other solutions are $(X_n,y_n)$ where $(5+4\sqrt2)(3+2\sqrt2)^n=y_n+X_n\sqrt2$; cf. wikipedia

I'm familiar with the pells equation with the one instead of -7. I'll look it up.

also see OEIS

Note that $(3+2\sqrt2)^n=y_n+X_n\sqrt2$ are solutions to $y^2-2X^2=1$

$y^2-8x^2= - 7$ & $y^2-8x^2=1$ both equation have related solution

OP needs more mathjax...

All solutions derives from $x+ay\equiv(\pm a+1)(a/2-1)^j\pmod{a^2-8}$ where $j=$0,2,4,...

as 7 is prime this is not too bad.
Rather than many interwoven sequences of generalized Fibonacci type, here there are just two subsequences  of $x_n, y_n$  with $x_n^2 - 8 y_n^2 = -7.$  They obey the same recurrence,
$$ x_{n+4} = 6 x_{n+2} - x_n , $$
$$ y_{n+4} = 6 y_{n+2} - y_n . $$
We could say that  one subsequence is  odd $n$   and the other even $n.$ $$  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{ccccccccccccc} 
n &-1 & 0 & 1 &  2 & 3 & 4 &5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 &10 & 11  \\  \hline
 x_n & -5 & -1 & 1 &  5 & 11 & 31 &65 & 181 & 379 & 1055 & 2209 & 6149 & 12875  \\ 
y_n & 2 & 1 & 1 &  2 & 4 & 11 & 23 & 64 & 134 & 373 & 781 & 2174 & 4552  \\ 
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Put slightly differently, any solution $(x,y)$  there is a new solution at $(3x+8y, x+3y)$  which gives larger values if $x,y,> 0.$
In the other direction, if you have a solution $(x,y)$   with large positive $x,y,$   a new solution with saller positive $(x,y)$  by taking $(3x-8y, -x+3y).$  Going backwards in this way, we must reach a solution with $(x,y > 0$  but at least one of $(3x-8y, -x+3y)$  negative or zero. The two "seed"  solutions are thus $(1,1)$  which backs up to $(-5,2),$   also $(5,2)$ which backs up to $(-1,1).$
For such "seed" solutions, the system $x,y > 0$, with $3x < 8y,$  and $x^2 - 8 y^2 = -7$  comes out to the inequality
$$       x < \sqrt {56} \; \approx \;  7.48 $$


Your answer is very nice, but for clarity I'm pointing out that you switched the role of $x$ and $y$ from OP

Also, what about the solutions where both $x$ and $y$ are negative?

The key to solving this equation is to recognize it as a generalized Pell equation:  $y^2-2X^2=-7.$
$($I write $X=2x.)\qquad$
Solutions to the regular Pell equation $y^2-2X^2=1$ are given by $(X,y)=(X_n,y_n),$
where $y_n+X_n\sqrt2=(3+2\sqrt2)^n, n=0,1,2,3,...\qquad$  Solutions to $y^2-2X^2=-7$
are given by $(X,y)=(X_n,y_n)$, where $y_n+X_n\sqrt2=(1+2\sqrt2)(3+2\sqrt2)^n, n=0,1,2,3,...$
and by $(X,y)=(X_m,y_m), $ where $y_m+X_m\sqrt2=(5+4\sqrt2)(3+2\sqrt2)^m, m=0,1,2,3,...$
The solutions $y$ are sequence A077446 in The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

I gave solutions for positive integers; obviously the signs of $X$ and/or $y$ could be changed and they would still be integer solutions
